# AngularJS Bind Attribute Presence

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to bind the *presence* of an attribute to a variable in AngularJS. Specifically, `sandbox` for an `iframe`. Say I have `$myCtrl.allowJavascript` as a variable, I want to do:

```
<iframe src="..." sandbox />
```

Where the `sandbox` attribute is present when `allowJavascript == false`, and I want the sandbox attribute to disappear when `allowJavascript == true`.

Does AngularJS have a mechanism for this?

The closest thing I could find was [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/bxobHiebfq0/3cXJ_9xjz94J), which basically says "it will just work for certain attributes"--but not for sandbox.

Comment: This is a potentially dangerous design.  The sandbox attribute only takes effect when the iframe is navigated to.  In other words, this might not do what you think it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For reusability you could make it generic along these lines:

```
app.directive("addAttr", function() {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch(attrs.addAttr, function(addAttr) {
      for (var key in addAttr) {
        if (addAttr[key]) element.attr(key, true);
        else element.removeAttr(key);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You'd use it like:

```
<iframe add-attr="{sandbox: allowJavaScript, someOtherAttr: someOtherVar}">
```

Answer (score 3):

You could create a custom directive for this if you wanted to.

```
app.directive('sandboxIf', function() {
  return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
            /* eval whatever was passed to sandbox-if="" 
               to see if it's true or false. */
            if(scope.$eval(attr.sandboxIf)) {
                elem.attr('sandbox','sandbox'); //sandbox="sandbox"
            }else{
                elem.removeAttr('sandbox');
            }
        }
    };
});
```

use would be like:

```
<iframe sandbox-if="foo"></iframe>
```

or even

```
<iframe sandbox-if="test()"></iframe>
```

where the controller would be like

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.foo = true;

   $scope.test = function() {
       return true;
   };
});
```

Comment: Thank you, that'll do just fine.